# repeat group analysis on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, summary

I have trouble finding the right code for the following problem:

My data table has multiple columns representing different variables representing repeated measurements. I would like to summarize the repeated measurements in R

[image]

```r
library(data.table)
data.table(structure(list(exp = c("480 p36", "480 p36", "480 p36", "480 p36", 
"480 p36", "480 p36"), well = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
    col = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006"), `T peak` = c(1.63, 
    1.67, 1.56, 1.47, 1.59, 1.55), `T rise` = c(0.2, 0.18, 0.18, 
    0.13, 0.14, 0.17), `T fall` = c(0.13, 0.16, 0.16, 0.15, 0.23, 
    0.2), TCT = c(0.86, 0.77, 0.73, 0.76, 0.71, 0.62), `D peak` = c(0.02, 
    0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01), `D valley` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), `D high` = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01), 
    `D low` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AUC = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
    0.01, 0, 0), Power = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0), CR = c(0.1, 
    0.12, 0.16, 0.14, 0.07, 0.05), RR = c(-0.1, -0.11, -0.11, 
    -0.12, -0.04, -0.04)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

In a first step I grouped the table with

```r
group <- group_by(output, col)
```

I made a variable vector:

```r
variables <- colnames(group[,4:15], do.NULL = TRUE)
```

I would like to summarize each variable grouped by column `col` and column
`exp`. Tried to summarize the data like mean, SEM, and count.

it works with

```r
summarize(group, mTCT = mean(`TCT`, na.rm = TRUE), SEM_TCT = sd(`TCT`,na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(n()), nTCT=n())
```

But I thought it would be better to replace every single column name with the variable vector. But that doesn't work.
Any advice?

Comment: Since you appear to be using `dpylr` for `group_by`: have a look at the `across` functionality (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html), or alternatively `summarize_at`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Welcome to stackoverflow.

Tried the following code.

```
data <- data.table(structure(list(exp = c("480 p36", "480 p36", "480 p36", "480 p36", 
"480 p36", "480 p36"), well = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
    col = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006"), `T peak` = c(1.63, 
    1.67, 1.56, 1.47, 1.59, 1.55), `T rise` = c(0.2, 0.18, 0.18, 
    0.13, 0.14, 0.17), `T fall` = c(0.13, 0.16, 0.16, 0.15, 0.23, 
    0.2), TCT = c(0.86, 0.77, 0.73, 0.76, 0.71, 0.62), `D peak` = c(0.02, 
    0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01), `D valley` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), `D high` = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01), 
    `D low` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AUC = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
    0.01, 0, 0), Power = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0), CR = c(0.1, 
    0.12, 0.16, 0.14, 0.07, 0.05), RR = c(-0.1, -0.11, -0.11, 
    -0.12, -0.04, -0.04)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"))



data %>%
    janitor::clean_names() %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer( # Tranform Wide -> Long
        cols = t_peak:rr,
        names_to = "variables"
    ) %>% 
    group_by(exp, col, variables) %>%
    summarise(
        mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
        sd = sd(value, na.rm = TRUE) / sqrt(n())
    )  %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider( # Return to "normal" state
        names_from = variables, 
        values_from = c(mean, sd)
    )
```

Hope this can help for the task.

Comment: Hi Victor, thank you. Indeed, this will work, but I would like to calculate mean and SEM on all variables, and try to avoid copy past the entire code for all of them...

Comment: I made the following variable vector: var <- as.vector(variables)
and then tried the across code: output %>% group_by(col) %>% summarize(across(all_of(var)), ~ mean(.x,na.rm = TRUE))

Comment: but this doesn't seem to work : Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..2`.
x Input `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
ℹ Input `..2` is `~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: col = "001".

Comment: I used this one which seem to work at the moment: exp_list <- unique(output$exp) #experiment list
for (i in  exp_list){
 suboutput <- subset(output, exp == i)
 sum <- suboutput %>% group_by(col) %>% summarise(across(everything(), list(mean = mean, sd = sd, c = length))) #works
 analysis <- sum[match(sort_order,as.numeric(sum$col)),] #works
 analysis <- analysis[,c(1,8:43)] #works
 out[[i]] <- analysis
} #works